# Represent python tuple in JSON

Tags: python, json, scikit-learn

In sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier, there is a parameter of

```
hidden_layer_sizes : tuple, length = n_layers - 2, default (100,)
```

In json, I have keys and values such as:

```
{
    "hidden_layer_sizes" : xxxx,
    "activation": "relu",
    "solver": "adam",
    "alpha": 0.0001,
}
```

How to represent the `(100, )` as JSON?

Comment: ``json.dumps((100,))``?

Comment: It depends. Who's parsing the json?

Comment: Front end will give me the json in POST request. I am testing it out in Postman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuple is not defined in [JSON](http://json.org/). You can use `JSON Array` instead, i.e. a `list`.

Alternatively, if you are controlling both encoding and decoding, you may encode it any way you wish (as long it is a valid JSON), and then decode it as `tuple`. Or, use a 3rd-party library that preserves Python `tuple`s, for example [jsonplus](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonplus) (in interest of full disclosure, I'm the author of that package).

Comment: Thanks for the info